# Multiple conditions in select statement based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-select-db

I have a multiple ctes. In my select statement I must filter values base on the conditions. This is my query.

```
SELECT roadName
    ,sum(roadLength) AS sumRoadLength
    ,avg(elevationDifference) AS eglAvgDepth
    ,avg(elevationDifference) AS pglAvgDepth
    ,
FROM cte3
GROUP BY roadName
ORDER BY roadName
```

Under "elevationDifference" there are lots of values ranging from -10 to +20 which are spread through "roadName". What i want to accomplished is that "eglAvgDepth" will return if all "elevationDifference" values are <0 and take the average. Same case with pglAvgDepth where values are >0.

I tried to add where statement but works only in eglAvgDepth

```
WHERE elevationDifference < 0
GROUP BY roadName
ORDER BY roadName
```

Comment: I assume that you mean that you want to calculate the two values based on whether *any* values are < 0 or > 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a conditional expression:

```
avg(case when elevationDifference < 0 then elevationDifference end) as eglAvgDepth,
avg(case when elevationDifference > 0 then elevationDifference end) as pglAvgDepth,
```

EDIT:

You have phrased this that you want the value based on whether all the values are positive or negative.  If so:

```
(case when max(elevationDifference) < 0 then avg(elevationDifference) end) as eglAvgDepth,
(case when max(elevationDifference) > 0 then avg(elevationDifference) end) as pglAvgDepth,
```

Comment: it worked and i add some function to avoid null values.```isnull (avg(case when elevationDifference < 0 then elevationDifference end),0) as eglAvgDepth,
isnull (avg(case when elevationDifference > 0 then elevationDifference end),0) as pglAvgDepth ```